# How does storing large numbers increase space complexity?

Tags: algorithm, space

For an assignment, I was supposed to write an algorithm which permits me to use at most n + O(log(n)) extra bits of memory (the details about what the algorithm was actually supposed to do isn't important here), where n is the size of an input array.

I submitted an algorithm that passes all of the test cases; however, my grader says that I am using more than n + O(log(n)) bits of memory. Their reason is that, as a part of my algorithm, I am adding the quantity (n * i) to every element in the array (where i = 1, 2, 3, ... n. i is an index variable in a loop). They are saying that for very large values of n, I will be using more memory to store the large numbers.

This leads me to the following question: is it true that my space complexity exceeds n + O(log(n)) bits by adding n * i to every number? My experience with algorithm analysis is quite limited, but I have personally never seen storing large numbers as a justification for increase in space complexity. But let's say for argument that it does increase complexity -- would I be using more than n + O(log(n)) bits?

I would like to formulate an argument for a challenge, but I just want to make sure that I am in the right before doing so.

Answer (score 1):

Let `b1` be the number of bits for each number before adding `(i*n)` to and `b2` be the number after that.

Inequality (1):

```
b2-b1 <= log(n*n) = 2log(n)
```

Proof (1):

```
Lemma 1: binary number is the best coding scheme for integers in memory.

Lemma 2: The sum of 2 integers always has the result shorter than the sum of each number's sizes.
```

From Inequality (1),

In the extreme case, if `b1 -> 0`, then `b2 = 2log(n)` so the increase in space is `2nlog(n)`. The total space would be `C + O(nlog(n))`

Disclaimer: that's not a proof for your problem, because I don't know exactly how many bits you used for each number at the beginning.